# Mongo insecure world dir

Tags: mongodb, terminal

I'm extremely new to using terminal commands. I'm trying to run an app locally on my Mac and i'm having difficulty with that so I'm trying to pick through the possible issues. The first one is the when using the mongod command I get an error of the flowing

/usr/local/bin/mongod:3: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log

Does this seem to be a problem or erroneous?

Comment: This seems to just be a warning letting you know that everybody has access to the directory (folder) that contains the database information.  As this is just a warning it will not stop your mongod from running, it is just an alert for a potentially unwanted configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Having /usr/local world writable is never a good idea. Normal permissions only allow the superuser (root) to write to these system directories.

To bring you back closer to the default run:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local
```

Furthermore you might want to clear the world writable bit on every subdir and file by running:

```
sudo chmod -R o-w /usr/local
```

This will mean you have to either start mongod as root or change the database path to somewhere you can write (for example in your homedir).

I run mongod on my developer machine using the following command:

```
mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --dbpath ~/mongo -v --profile 2
```

This means the following:

- `--bind_ip 127.0.0.1` make sure others in your network can't access your database
- `--dbpath ~/mongo` save database files in your home dir in the directory mongo
- `-v` show queries that are being executed
- `--profile 2` shows performance and profile information on queries

You should run `mongod -h` to see all available options.